# Some of order confirmation emails are not send

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

So I have a Magento 2.3 that's been running for a long time with no issues. There hasn't been any major change in the past days but suddenly some - not all - of the order confirmation emails are not sent to the customer/ admin. It doesn't work even when I click the send email button from the order. Had a look at the logs but couldn't find something. Does anyone have a clue where I should be looking?